# GCP Dataflow template creation issue through python SDK

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, dataflow

My template command is python gcp_parquet.py --runner DataflowRunner --project project_ID --staging_location STAGING_LOCATION --temp_location TEMP_LOCATION --template_location TEMPLATE_LOCATION --experiment=use_beam_bq_sink --region us-east1

I am getting the following error:
**Exception: Dataflow only supports Python versions 2 and 3.5+, got: (3, 8)**

I am using python 3.8.3 in virtual env.

Please help me solve this issue.

Comment: type in terminal
python -V and you get a version of python

Comment: It's 3.8.3 version

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't look like Beam Python SDK supports Python 3.8 yet.

The code throws the error is [here](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/python/apache_beam/runners/dataflow/internal/apiclient.py#L1094).

Comment: This is correct. The upcoming 2.23.0 release is expected to add Python 3.8 support.